# Measuring mood/confusion in text analysis

Tags: text, sentiment-analysis

I am looking to measure the level of confusion in series of short texts. I was wondering if anyone knows if there exists a "Confusion" dictionary similar to the sentiment dictionaries that are easily available. Basically, I'm looking for a collection of words or phrases that signal confusion. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Means do you want sentiment analysis of your custom the content or keyword extraction?

Comment: "Confusion" in the sense are you meaning Irony/Sarcasm Detection ???